# Mining block are not accepted if BIP related values changed to 0 or 1

Tags: litecoin, mining-reward, scrypt, bip, cpuminer

I am creating own alt from LiteCoin source. So I have changed `hashGenesisBlock` , `hashMerkleRoot` , `nonce` , `timestamp` etc.Things are working fine if i don't make BIP34Height , `BIP65Height` , `BIP66Height` & `BIP34Hash` value to **`1`** .While doing mining using cpuminer generated hash/blocks are not accepting and that's why blocks are not getting generated/added.

If I change that BIP( BIP34Height , BIP65Height & BIP66Height and BIP34Hash) values(not default which is litecoin values), that generated hash/block should be accepted from cpu miner or any other third party mining binary. ***I've tried by setting value to 0 & 1 both but same result things are not working as expected***.. Here is log URL generated from mining : https://gist.github.com/adneerav/591e61657292e6c6561a26b69dc78870

If I don't change that BIP values things are working fine.Generated blocks are accepted to add.Please check log which is generated from mining process. https://gist.github.com/adneerav/0b30889d3950662201734776b926903a#file-old_script_mining-log-L84

For testing and initial setup i am doing things on LAN.All things are working fine if i don't change BIP values only(changing only genesis , merke minimum chain etc)

I know for this BIP related conceptual should be clear but I've not found any example & proper documentation so I came here to make things clear if anyone can provide more details/document/blogs and help me to solve this things.

Can anyone please help me in this issue ?

Please let me know if this community is not for AltCoin/Crypto Currency questions/answer I mean only for Bitcoin related not for other crypto.

**Note :** 
Before I come to this I've already ask same thing : https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/issues/538

Thanks